# Invoke <cffile action=upload> MIME validation algorithm for a file that is not in form scope?

Tags: coldfusion

Is it possible to invoke the MIME validation behavior of `<cffile action=upload>` without a user upload in the `form` scope? I have considered manually placing a file object into the form scope, but don't offhand know what Java type it would be (it's not a `fileReadBinary` result object, that's for certain), or if such behavior would be guaranteed-portable across CF releases.

As a worst case solution, I'm considering just doing HTTP calls to myself with the files attached and running `cffile` from the endpoint, but that seems a bit ridiculous.

Comment: How are the files being stored on the ColdFusion server if not by user upload?

Comment: Are you trying to do an upload via AJAX?

Comment: Regarding MIME type validation, I'll just point to a couple of older things by Pete Freitag :: https://www.petefreitag.com/item/701.cfm and https://teratech.com/020-secrets-of-high-security-coldfusion-code-with-pete-freitag/. To quote Pete, "Never trust a mime."